# How to make a barchart where the x-axis includes gaps

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'd like the x-axis of my barchart to be a continuous scale.

Here is my data:

```
list(
 Century = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
 CenturyLabel = c("1st", "Bit later", "", "", "Post-Roman"), 
 Value = c(.2, .3, 0, 0, .4) ) %>% as_tibble()
```

I'm hoping to see bars for the 1st, 2nd, and 5th centuries with gaps for the 3rd and 4th.

Comment: `df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Century, y = Value)) +
  geom_col()` ?

Comment: In general you do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040245/how-to-increase-the-space-between-the-bars-in-a-bar-plot-in-ggplot2 but ggplot doens't make it easy to specify different gaps between different bars (since that makes the axis meaningless).  Might need to do some post-processing in another program for that.

Comment: Another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100500/specific-spaces-between-bars-in-a-barplot-ggplot2-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to define your x-axis variable as a *factor*.

```r
library("dplyr")

df <- tibble(
 Century = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
 CenturyLabel = c("1st", "Bit later", "", "", "Post-Roman"), 
 Value = c(.2, .3, 0, 0, .4) )

df$CenturyFactor <- factor(df$Century, labels = df$CenturyLabel), ordered = TRUE)
```

You can then use `CenturyFactor` as x-axis variable and you'll see a gap with any correct plotting libraries... With the big caveat that any duplicate labels cause the centuries to be merged!

One way around this is to plot `Century` (1 to 5) but tweak the labels to show `CenturyLabel`. This will be library-specific. No factors needed.

Using ggplot2:

```r
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Century, y = Value)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = df$CenturyLabel, breaks = df$Century)
```

[image: Plot with gaps]

Comment: Actually the duplicate labels are merged into one factor level. So that's not fully working. I can't manage off the top of my head, at least not without setting the x labels explicitly which is not very elegant.

Comment: For this solution to work, you must not have duplicate labels. In your example, centuries 3 and 4 are merged into one factor level because they both have `""` as label.

Comment: Thank you, though pity about the duplicates;  how would I set the x labels explicitly?